# Button click doesnot invoke desired method from activity

Tags: android

I am new to android and followed the "Building Your First App" tutorial from http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/index.html
my problem is that when i click on send button nothing happens.

Main.Manifest code:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="sendMessage"
    android:text="@string/button_send" />
```

Main.java Code

```
public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "com.example.myfirstapp.MESSAGE";
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }
    public void sendMessage(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);
        EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_message);
        String message = editText.getText().toString();
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
    }
```

Program has no error but do nothing on click event

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You missed

```
  startActivity(intent);
```

Also Initializing editText in `onCreate` would be better

```
EditText editText;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_message);
}
```

In sendMesage

```
public void sendMessage(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, editText.getText().toString());
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Comment: +1 for be first to ans..cant understand why people still giving answers

Comment: @KalpeshLakhani Sometimes you don't see that someone answered the question.

Comment: @KalpeshLakhani thank you for the upvote i guess it would be ok for others to answer untill its a exactly duplicate

Comment: the comment box hint states that comment should not be used for +1 and this sort of things

Comment: @AliAlamiri then you should delete your answer

Comment: @blackbelt I made the effort of writing it. Would be a waste to delete it.

Answer (score 2):

You're not starting the activity. When you create an intent, you need to call the `startActivity;` method and pass the intent to it.

```
public void sendMessage(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);
    EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_message);
    String message = editText.getText().toString();
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
    startActivity(intent); //need this
}
```

Read [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#startActivity%28android.content.Intent%29)

Answer (score 1):

in `sendMessage()` method in the last line add this. 
`startActivity(intent)`

You have not started the activity..